# How to render a Twig template after AJAX call

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, twig, timber

We're operating an ecommerce site. In order to refresh our mini-cart in the header, I'm calling a PHP function via AJAX and could either receive a JSON with all data or an already compiled twig file. For my feeling this is not really best practice, since the ajax call could get very large with all that DOM elements inside. My approche is to use the data from the JSON file and render it from the javascript side. My two questions are:

1. Whats the best practice to render/compile data into the template? PHP render or from the JS side?
2. I've read about twig.js but not quite how to use this - specially in wordpress, I have no idea where to place the project in order to make it work.

Inside timber.js I could find some test, which I tried to then addapt to my code, but unfortunatly it did not work. This is what I used:

```
const Twig = require('../twig-js').factory();

const {twig} = Twig;
```

I would like to see something like this:

```
success:function(response) {
   $('.cart-dropdown').load('twig-template.twig', response);
}
```

Any approche appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The render of the Twig template should come to you in response from the server.  That is, in success you should have ready html.

```
$html = $twig->render( 'twig-template.twig', $args );
die( $html );
```